# Hook into create_category

Tags: hooks, categories

I'm trying to in some way hook into when a new category is created. What I would like to do is to see the term and slug that was created and log them/email them. I have tried to hook in to create_category(). That only gives me an ID, not the term and slug. Would be great if someone could lead me on the right track.

Comment: Did you research for `create_category` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the get_term_by() function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

```
// get the category object
$category = get_term_by( 'id', $category_id, 'category');

// use the object to get your values
$name = $category->name;
$slug = $category->slug;
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 /*
  Plugin Name: Xml Write
  Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/plugins/
  Description: This is post category xml write plugin
  Version: 1.6
  Author URI:
 */

add_action('admin_menu', 'xmlwrite_admin_actions');

function xmlwrite_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page('xmlwrite', 'xmlwrite', 'manage_options', xmlwrite, 'xmlwrite_admin');
}

add_action('add_category_form_pre', 'update_category_function');
add_action('edit_category', 'update_category_function');
add_action('delete_category', 'update_category_function');

function update_category_function($category_id) {
    $categories = get_categories($category_id);

    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openURI("text.xml");
    $xml->startDocument();
    $xml->setIndent(true);

    $xml->startElement('Categories');

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $xml->startElement("Category");
        $xml->writeRaw($category->name);
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->startElement("url");
        $xml->writeRaw(esc_url(get_category_link($category->term_id)));
        $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();

    header('Content-type: tet/xml');
    $xml->flush();
}
```